# Deprive all users permission from SharePoint site except specific user by Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, flow, power-automate, modern-team-site

I'm using Modern experience in SharePoint Online.

I want to deprive all users permission from SharePoint site except for a specific user by PowerAutomate.

I know this is possible by PowerShell.

But I want to do it regularly, so I want to do it with Power Automate. Is it possible?

I would appreciate it if you could teach me how to do it. Thank you for any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using flow to remove user site permission, we will need to use rest api and call the http request to do so. The most default way can be remove user from permission group, and a simple demo will be like below:
[image]

The GRP2 is the group name and I use the method `removeByLoginName`. This is not the only way, you can try other options with Rest api.

Here are some references for rest api, you can have a try with them:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-and-remove-users-from-security-group-in-sharepoint-2016-using-rest-api/

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1c70bfb1-039d-43cd-94b5-6138893bde8b/rest-api-removedelete-sp-user-from-group?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Also some 3rd party actions are available for handling such process:
https://plumsail.com/docs/actions/v1.x/flow/how-tos/sharepoint/create-sp-group-add-users.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My requirements have changed a bit so I would be very happy if you could see my latest questions.